# unexpected error in unorderd_map when I tried to print the map's elements on the screen

Tags: c++

I'm new in using unordered_map and I'm facing a problem here the problem is printing the map on the screen I can't count the map here and I don't really know what's the problem can any one please help me

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream> 
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string new_number, address, name;
      unordered_map<string, pair<vector<string>, string>> contact;
      unordered_map<string, pair<vector<string>, string>>::iterator it = contact.begin(), it1;
vector<string>v;
cin >> name;
cout << "Enter the number:" << endl;
cin >> new_number;
v.push_back(new_number);
contact[name] = make_pair(v, address);
cout << it->first;

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `contact.begin()` after you have set the value of `contact[name]`, not before.

Move

```
unordered_map<string, pair<vector<string>, string>>::iterator it = contact.begin();
```

after the line

```
contact[name] = make_pair(v, address);
```